# Macro adding line on pivot chart/origin position in pivot chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts, pivot-table

Excel 2007, VB 6.3

I created a pivot chart (chart from pivot table) type xlCylinderColStacked. Axis y scale: minimum 0%, maximum 2%.
I would like to add a horizontal line at a target level of 0.7% (target is not fixed, but should be taken from another cell in another sheet: **Target = Sheets("equivalenti").Range("N6").Value**)
Command should be something like

```
 .Shapes.AddLine(60, vertical_position, 940, vertical_position).Line
```

I tried to create a formula to calculate vertical_position given .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale, .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale, .ChartArea.Top, .PlotArea.Height but I can't find a solution. Any idea?

Basically, it would be easy to place the horizontal line if I knew exact position of the origin (0% on axis y) from the top-left corner which is taken as a reference for the .top and .left measures on the ChartArea.

I report below full code for two out of fours charts (correction is 8 in one case and 27 in another -- I only care vertical position)

```
        Sub Macro2()

        With Sheets("conveyor_mese")
            .Select

            .Cells.Select

        End With
        Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "dati!R1C1:R9999C28", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
            TableDestination:="conveyor_mese!R1C1", TableName:= _
            "Tabella_pivot1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        With ActiveChart
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range("conveyor_mese!$A$1:$C$28")
            .ChartType = xlCylinderColStacked
             .Legend.Position = xlBottom
            .Rotation = 0
            .Elevation = 0
            .Perspective = 10
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1").PivotFields("Anno")
             .Orientation = xlRowField
             .Position = 1
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1").PivotFields("Mese")
             .Orientation = xlRowField
             .Position = 2
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1").PivotFields("anno")
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With
        With Worksheets("conveyor_mese")
            .ChartObjects(1).Top = .Rows("25").Top
            .ChartObjects(1).Left = .Columns("B").Left
            .ChartObjects(1).Height = 500
            .ChartObjects(1).Width = 330

        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotChartActiveFields = False
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1").CalculatedFields
            .Add "% SCARTO BUCHI", "='Somma di  BUCHI'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO VENATURE", "='Somma di  VENATURE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO BASSE", "='Somma di LASTRE BASSE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% CAUSA FOAM", "='SCARTI CONVEYOR'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% CAUSA TAGLIO", "='SCARTI TAGLIO'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% TOTALE SCARTI", "='TOTALE SCARTI'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO BORDO LATERALE", "='Somma di BORDO LATERALE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO FORCHE", "='Somma di FORCHE MULETTO'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO CREPE", "='Somma di  CREPE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% CROSTE LATERALI", "='Somma di  CROSTE LATERALI' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% ALTRO", "='Conteggio di ALTRI DIFETTI'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO ROTTURE MECC. FILO", "='Somma di ROTTURE MECCANICHE FILO' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO ROTTURE MECC. PONTE CARICO", "='Somma di ROTTURE MECCANICHE PONTE CARICO' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO ROTTURE MECC. SQUADRATRICI", "='Somma di ROTTURE MECCANICHE SQUADRATRICI' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO RIGHE NON PARALLELE", "='Somma di RIGHE NON PARALLELE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% CROSTE SUPERFICIALI", "='Somma di  CROSTE SUPERFICIALI' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO CORTE", "='Somma di LASTRE CORTE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1")
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO BUCHI").Orientation = xlDataField

            .PivotFields("% CROSTE LATERALI").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO CREPE").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO BORDO LATERALE").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO VENATURE").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("% CROSTE SUPERFICIALI").Orientation = xlDataField
        End With
        Set pvtTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot1")
        For Each pvtField In pvtTable.DataFields

            pvtField.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        Next pvtField
        Worksheets("conveyor_mese").ChartObjects(1).Activate

        With ActiveChart
            .PlotArea.Select

            Selection.Height = 350
            Selection.Top = 125
            .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelShow)

            .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)

            With .ChartTitle
                .Text = _
                    "REPARTO TAGLIO - IMPIANTO DI TAGLIO LINEA BASSA DENSITA'" & Chr(13) & "Dettaglio delle cause di scarto lastre per DIFETTO SCHIUMA - " & Chr(13) & "Mensile  "
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Axes(xlValue)
                 .MajorUnit = 0.002
                .MaximumScale = 0.015
                .MinimumScale = 0
            End With
            With .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 50, 80, 300, 130)
                  With .TextFrame
                    .Characters.Text = "Venature : striature superficiali con sciami di bolle" & vbLf & _
                       "Buchi : bolle o buchi superficiali con diametro superiore a 3 mm e numerosità >3 per lastra " & vbLf & _
                       "Crepe : crepe e stracciature prevalentemente laterali formatesi durante la schiumatura" & vbLf & _
                       "Bordo laterale : struttura cellulare molto orientata con colore e consistenza non adeguata" & vbLf & _
                       "Croste laterali : presenza di croste sul bordo laterale riconducibili ad un profilo inadeguato  del blocco grezzo."
                    .Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True
                     .Characters(54, 7).Font.Bold = True
                    .Characters(146, 7).Font.Bold = True
                    .Characters(234, 16).Font.Bold = True
                    .Characters(325, 17).Font.Bold = True
                 End With
                 .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                 With .Line
                    .Weight = 0.75
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(191, 191, 191)
                 End With
            End With
            Target_s = Sheets("equivalenti").Range("N6").Value
            With .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 670, 270, 130, 16)
               With .TextFrame.Characters
                    .Text = "Obiettivo " & Sheets("equivalenti").Range("N5").Value & "     " & Format(Target_s, "Percent")
                    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                End With
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 80, 77)
            End With
            X = .ChartArea.Left + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideLeft
            Y = .ChartArea.Top + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideTop + 8
            x1 = X + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideWidth
            step = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Height / (ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale)
            y1 = step * (ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale - (Target_s - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale))
              With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, X, Y + y1, x1, Y + y1)
                .Select
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 80, 77)
                .Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
                 .Line.Weight = 2.75
             End With
            NameLine = Selection.Name
            .GapDepth = 50
            .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 50
        End With
        '********************************************************************************************************
        '********************************************************************************************************
        '********************************************************************************************************
        Sheets("taglio_mese").Select
        Sheets("taglio_mese").Cells.Select
        Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "dati!R1C1:R9999C28", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
            TableDestination:="taglio_mese!R1C1", TableName:= _
            "Tabella_pivot5", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        With ActiveChart
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range("'taglio_mese'!$A$1:$C$28")
            .ChartType = xlCylinderColStacked
            .Legend.Position = xlTop
            .Rotation = 0
            .Elevation = 0
            .Perspective = 10
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot5").PivotFields("ANNO")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot5").PivotFields("MESE")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With
        With Worksheets("taglio_mese")
            .ChartObjects(1).Top = .Rows("25").Top
            .ChartObjects(1).Left = .Columns("B").Left
            .ChartObjects(1).Height = 1100
            .ChartObjects(1).Width = 500
        End With
        ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotChartActiveFields = False
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot5").PivotFields("mese")
                .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
            End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot5").CalculatedFields
            .Add "% SCARTO BUCHI", "='Somma di  BUCHI'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO VENATURE", "='Somma di  VENATURE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO BASSE", "='Somma di LASTRE BASSE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% CAUSA FOAM", "='SCARTI CONVEYOR'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% CAUSA TAGLIO", "='SCARTI TAGLIO'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% TOTALE SCARTI", "='TOTALE SCARTI'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO BORDO LATERALE", "='Somma di BORDO LATERALE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO FORCHE", "='Somma di FORCHE MULETTO'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO CREPE", "='Somma di  CREPE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% CROSTE LATERALI", "='Somma di  CROSTE LATERALI' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% ALTRO", "='Conteggio di ALTRI DIFETTI'/'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO ROTTURE MECC. FILO", "='Somma di ROTTURE MECCANICHE FILO' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO ROTTURE MECC. PONTE CARICO", "='Somma di ROTTURE MECCANICHE PONTE CARICO' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO ROTTURE MECC. SQUADRATRICI", "='Somma di ROTTURE MECCANICHE SQUADRATRICI' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO RIGHE NON PARALLELE", "='Somma di RIGHE NON PARALLELE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% CROSTE SUPERFICIALI", "='Somma di  CROSTE SUPERFICIALI' /'prod. Giorno'", True
            .Add "% SCARTO CORTE", "='Somma di LASTRE CORTE' /'prod. Giorno'", True
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot5")
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO BASSE").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO FORCHE").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO ROTTURE MECC. FILO").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO ROTTURE MECC. PONTE CARICO").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO ROTTURE MECC. SQUADRATRICI").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO RIGHE NON PARALLELE").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("% SCARTO CORTE").Orientation = xlDataField
        End With
        Set pvtTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tabella_pivot5")
        For Each pvtField In pvtTable.DataFields
            pvtField.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        Next pvtField
        Worksheets("taglio_mese").ChartObjects(1).Activate
        With ActiveChart
            .PlotArea.Select
            .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelShow)
            .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
            With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
                With .AxisTitle
                    .Text = "MESE"
                    .Font.Size = 16
                End With
                .TickLabels.Font.Size = 16
            End With
            With .Axes(xlValue)
                .MajorUnit = 0.0005
                .MinimumScale = 0
                .MaximumScale = 0.005
                .TickLabels.Font.Size = 16
            End With
            With .ChartTitle
                 .Text = _
                 "TOTALE % SCARTO LASTRE TAGLIO LD"
                 .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                 .Font.Size = 28
            End With
            With .Legend.Font
                .Size = 16
            End With
            Target_t = Sheets("equivalenti").Range("N7").Value
            With .Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 1690, 270, 150, 24)
                With .TextFrame.Characters
                     .Text = "Obiettivo " & Sheets("equivalenti").Range("N5").Value & "     " & Format(Target_t, "Percent")
                     .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                     .Font.Size = 14
                End With
                 .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 80, 77)
            End With
            X = .ChartArea.Left + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideLeft
            Y = .ChartArea.Top + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideTop + 27
            x1 = X + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideWidth
            step = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Height / (ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale)
            y1 = step * (ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale - (Target_t - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale))
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, X, Y + y1, x1, Y + y1)
                 .Select
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                 .Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
                 .Line.Weight = 3
             End With
            NameLine = Selection.Name
        End With
        For X = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
            With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(X)
                .DataLabels.Font.Size = 16
             End With
        Next X
            With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
                .SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(69, 114, 167)
               .SeriesCollection(2).Interior.Color = RGB(170, 70, 67)
                .SeriesCollection(3).Interior.Color = RGB(137, 165, 78)
                .SeriesCollection(4).Interior.Color = RGB(113, 88, 143)
                .SeriesCollection(5).Interior.Color = RGB(65, 152, 175)
                .SeriesCollection(6).Interior.Color = RGB(147, 169, 207)
                .SeriesCollection(7).Interior.Color = RGB(209, 147, 146)
            End With
[...]
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To create the Line (in a module):

```
Public NameLine As String

Sub LinePt()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 14").Activate
    x = Selection.Left + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideLeft + Range("C10").Value
    y = Selection.Top + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideTop + Range("C9").Value
    x1 = x + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideWidth
    step = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Height / (ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale)
    y1 = step * (ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale - (Range("C8").Value - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale))

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, x, y + y1, x1, y + y1).Select
    NameLine = Selection.Name
End Sub
```

To change in accordance at a value stored in C8 (Inside the sheet):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    xx = ActiveCell.Address

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 14").Activate
    x = Selection.Left + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideLeft + Range("C10").Value
    y = Selection.Top + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideTop + Range("C9").Value
    x1 = x + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideWidth
    step = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Height / (ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale)
    y1 = step * (ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale - (Range("C8").Value - ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale))

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(NameLine)).Select
    Selection.Top = y + y1
    Selection.Left = x
    Selection.Width = x1 - x

    Range(xx).Select
End Sub
```

The cells C9 and C10 are two value of correction (value = 4) that I don't find where you are stored (property). If you change size or value the line update the position. If you resize the chart, not.

Comment: **WONDERFUL, IT WORKS** I only don't understand what the value of correction is and how it works. Is it fixed value at 4? Why? And why using '+ Range("C10").Value' and '+ Range("C9").Value' rather than '+4'?

Comment: I do't found where excel store this value, than I take these values from two cells C9 & C10 to change and calibrate... I suppose can change in base of resolution & Excel Versions...

Comment: It must depend on something else. Because it does not work regularly!!! Overall, it works in two out of four charts (when it doesn't work properly, it is because the vertical position of the connector is slightly higher than the real target value).

Answer (score 0):

I've not found where the value it's stored, but we can obtain the value dinamically for every chart using this macro (to start only the first time):

```
Public NameLine As String
Public DisX, DisY As Double

Sub FindDisXY()
    Dim TmpX, TmpY As Double

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 14").Activate
    TmpX = ActiveChart.PlotArea.Left
    TmpY = ActiveChart.PlotArea.Top
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Left = -12
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Top = -12

    DisX = -ActiveChart.PlotArea.Left
    DisY = -ActiveChart.PlotArea.Top
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Left = TmpX
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Top = TmpY
End Sub
```

This macro move the PlotArea in one area NOT POSSIBLE (-12,-12) after Get the Left & Top and move back the PlotArea.
The values of Left & Top gets, are equals to the disallignment... Try to use with your different charts. If Work, ***we have*** a possible solution. I search a lot, by I don't found this value stored.
The two values shall be substitute in the lines:

```
x = Selection.Left + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideLeft + DisY
y = Selection.Top + ActiveChart.PlotArea.InsideTop + DisX
```

Comment: The DisX and DisY variables are equal to 4 in each of the four charts in which I tested your solution. Yet the vertical position of the connector is correctly calculated only in two cases. I'll continue working on this...

Comment: But with manual adjustement, witch value you need to add ? The chart are different type, if yes, whitch are the differences ?